# removing electrical sockets from bathroom

Tags: electrical, bathroom

I'm in the process of planning a conversion of a room, from kitchen to bathroom.

I live in the UK and there are regulations prohibiting electrical sockets to be within 3m of a bath or shower, essentially meaning I need to have them all removed - there are 2 single sockets, 4 double sockets, and a fused outlet for the cooker.

My question is, how should I go about making these outlets safe so I can ideally fill & skim over the top of where they were - should the wires be removed from the walls, or is it safe to have them disconnected from the fuse box and terminate the other ends, then plaster over the top?
They are part of the top floor ring circuit, so I may need to connect them together if those wires also power other sockets.

I would hire an electritian to do anything required with the fuse box, and am competent enough to wire connector blocks, sockets etc myself. What is the correct approach?

Comment: No socket (receptacle) within 3 m of a shower or bath?! If true, this amounts to mandating a rather large bathroom. I think you should confirm your original information and find out if there are exceptions. In the US the shock hazard in bathrooms is mitigated by requiring GFCI (Residual Current Device or RCD) on the receptacle in the bathroom. I would be very surprised if the UK code disallows all receptacles within 3 m of a shower.

Comment: If you want to plaster them then the wires need to be gone completely, at least in North American rules which require every electrical box to be accessible with thumbs and a screwdriver, without disassembling the building in any way.  There can't be a chance of someone energizing them if they're buried.

Comment: @JimStewart, yes - jammypeach is correct. The only electricity sockets allowed in UK bathrooms are 110V Shaver sockets - not standard UK 240V sockets. As to the correct solution? Don't know, but I do remember that there are very strict rules in the UK about the amount of electrical rework that a homeowner can do.

Comment: Is the 110 V 'shaver socket' protected by a RCD? What about a receptacle for a hair dryer? Is hair drying in the UK done in a bedroom rather than in a bathroom? What about a dental irrigation device? Are these allowed near a lavatory faucet?

Comment: thanks for the comments guys, to clarify, the regs state that there can be no 240v sockets within 3m of a bath or shower, any installed electrical equipment (e.g whirlpool bath, extractor fan) must be wired permanently and with an RCD, however shaver sockets are allowed. Also, @PeteCon is correct there is a strict limit on what I'm allowed to do myself, but I can do it and have it checked by the council & certified. Here's more info on the regs: http://electrical.theiet.org/wiring-matters/53/section-701/index.cfm

Comment: Are these shaver sockets two hots 180 deg out of phase each 55 V AC compared to ground? AsI understand it this is how electrical tools are powered at outdoor construction sites in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove the receptacle and add a blank plate?  That would seem to at least comply with the intent of the regulation.